# Prevent vim from starting in a shell if it is already running in background

Tags: shell, vim

When using vim inside my Bash-shell, I will sometimes use `Ctrl-Z` to leave vim and do other things in the shell. Later, I will then use the `fg` command to return to vim. However, it sometimes happens that instead of returning to vim with `fg`, I start a new instance of vim when I find some file I want to edit. That means I have two instances of vim running in the same shell, and I don't like this idea. I want to force myself to only run one instance per shell.

Is there some way I can block vim from starting if one instance is already running in the current shell? Can this be implemented in the `.vimrc` instead of making a shell script that runs when I type `vim`?

Comment: Are you certain this wouldn’t interfere with your workflow? Very often I suspend Vim precisely to open another instance on a different file someplace else. Perhaps it’d be better to have $PS1 indicate that the current shell already has a backgrounded Vim.

Comment: @phg Well the severe case is when you attempt to open a file that was already opened by an old instance. Since I don't use the swapfile thing, I am not notified of that. Having the same file open in two instances is bad IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in your .bashrc might work, but may hit some false positives:

```
alias vim='if jobs | grep -q vim; then fg; else command vim; fi'
```

Comment: You could drop the absolute path and use `command vim` instead. And `$@` needs to be double quoted.

Comment: Noted and incorporated.

Comment: Alias don't do parameter expansion - `"$@"` makes no sense there. Did you  mean to make a function?

Comment: Fair point; I don't use `alias` very often, so I forget that passing parameters is already handled automagically.